# How to map an array of values for y_true to a single value in order to compare to y_pred in a Tensorflow loss function (Tensorflow/Tensorflow Quantum)

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function, tensorflow-quantum

I am trying to implement the circuits listed on page 8 in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.10876.pdf using Tensorflow Quantum (TFQ). I have done so previously for a subset of circuits using Qiskit, and ended up with accuracies that can be found on page 14 in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.09887.pdf. In TFQ, my accuracies are way down. I think this delta originates because in TFQ, I only used 1 observable Pauli Z operator on the first qubit, and the circuits do not seem to "transfer all knowledge" to the first qubit. I place this in quotes, because I am sure there is a better way to describe this. In Qiskit on the other hand, 16 states (4^2) get mapped to 2 states.

***My question: how can I get my accuracies back up?***
Potential answer a): some method of "transferring all information" to a single qubit, potentially an ancilla qubit, and doing a readout on this qubit. 
Potential answer b) placing a Pauli Z observable on all qubits (4 in total), mapping half of the 16 states to a label 0 and the other half to a label 1. I attempted this in the code below.

My attempt at answer b):

I have a Tensorflow Quantum (TFQ) circuit implemented in Tensorflow. The circuit has multiple observables, which I try to bring together in my loss function. I prefer to use as many standard components as possible, but need to map my quantum states to a label in order to determine the loss. I think what I am trying to achieve is not unique to TFQ. I define my model in the following way:

```
def circuit():
  data_qubits = cirq.GridQubit.rect(4, 1)  
  circuit = cirq.Circuit()
  ...
  return circuit, [cirq.Z(data_qubits[0]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[1]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[2]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[3])]
model_circuit, model_readout = circuit()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
  # The PQC layer returns the expected value of the readout gate, range [-1,1].
  tfq.layers.PQC(model_circuit, model_readout),
])

# compile model
model.compile(
  loss = loss_mse,
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
  metrics=[])
```

in loss_mse (Mean Square Error), I receive a (32, 4) tensor for y_pred. One row could look like

```
[-0.2, 0.33, 0.6, 0.3]
```

This would have to be first mapped from [-1,1] to a binarized version of [0,1], so that it looks like:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now, a table lookup needs to happen, which tells if this combination is 0 or 1. Finally, the regular (y_true-y_pred)^2 can be performed by that row, followed by a np.sum on all rows. I tried to implement this:

```
def get_label(measurement):
  if measurement == [0,0,0,0]: return 0
  ...
  elif measurement == [1,1,1,1]: return 0
  else: return -1

def py_call(y_true, y_pred):
  # cast tensor to numpy
  y_pred_np = np.asarray(y_pred)
  loss = np.zeros((len(y_pred))) # could be a single variable with += within the loop
  # evalaute all 32 samples
  for pred in range(len(y_pred_np)):
      # map, binarize and lookup
      y_labelled = get_label([0 if y<0 else 1 for y in y_pred_np[pred]])
      # regular loss comparison
      loss[pred] = (y_labelled - y_true[pred])**2
  # reduce
  loss = np.sum(loss)/len(y_true)
return loss

@tf.function
def loss_mse(y_true, y_pred):
  external_list = []
  loss = tf.py_function(py_call, inp=[y_true, y_pred], Tout=[tf.float64])
  return loss
```

However, the system appears to still expect a (32,4) tensor. I would have thought I could simply provide a single loss values (float). My question: how can I map multiple values for y_true to a single number in order to compare with a single y_pred value in a tensorflow loss function?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there are a couple of things going on here. To answer your question

> how can I map multiple values for y_true to a single number in order to compare with a single y_pred value in a tensorflow loss function ?

What you might want is some kind of `tf.reduce_*` function like `tf.reduce_mean` or `tf.reduce_sum`. This function will allow you to apply this reduction operation accross a given tensor axis allowing you to convert a tensor of shape (32, 4) to a tensor of shape (32,) or a tensor of shape (4,). Here is a quick snippet:

```py
@tf.function
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  # y_true is shape (32, 4)
  # y_pred is shape (32, 4)

  # Scale from [-1, 1] to [0, 1]
  y_true += 1
  y_true /= 2
  y_pred += 1
  y_pred /= 2

  # These are now both (32,) with the reduction of taking the mean applied along
  # the second axis.
  reduced_true = tf.reduce_mean(y_true, axis=1)
  reduced_pred = tf.reduce_mean(y_pred, axis=1)

  # Now a scalar loss.
  loss = tf.reduce_mean((reduce_true - reduced_pred) ** 2)
  return loss
```

Now the above isn't exactly what you want, since it's not super clear to me at least what exact reduction rules you have in mind for taking something like `[0,1,1,1] -> 0` vs `[0,0,0,0] -> 1`.

Another thing I will also mention is that if you want JUST the sum of these Pauli Operators in cirq that you have term by term in the list `[cirq.Z(data_qubits[0]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[1]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[2]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[3])]` and all you care about is the final sum of these expectations, you could just as easily do:

```py
my_operator = sum([cirq.Z(data_qubits[0]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[1]),
  cirq.Z(data_qubits[2]), cirq.Z(data_qubits[3])])

print(my_op)
```

Which should give something like:
`cirq.PauliSum(cirq.LinearDict({frozenset({(cirq.GridQubit(0, 0), cirq.Z)}): (1+0j), frozenset({(cirq.GridQubit(0, 1), cirq.Z)}): (1+0j), frozenset({(cirq.GridQubit(0, 2), cirq.Z)}): (1+0j), frozenset({(cirq.GridQubit(0, 3), cirq.Z)}): (1+0j)}))`

Which is also compatable as a readout operation in the PQC layer. Lastly if would recommend reading through some of the snippets and examples here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/api_docs/python/tfq/layers/PQC

and here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/api_docs/python/tfq/layers/Expectation

Which give a pretty good description of how the input and output signatures of the functions look as well as the shapes you can expect from them.